# How to hightlight CayleyGraph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, group-theory

```
g = CayleyGraph[SymmetricGroup[3], 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 3 Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1, -Sqrt[3]/2}, {0, 
     Sqrt[3]/2}, {-2.4, -2.4 Sqrt[3]/2}, {2.4, -2.4 Sqrt[3]/
       2}, {1, -Sqrt[3]/2}}]
```

[image]

I want hightlight the path from 1→4→5→1, but I don't how why this code don't work...

```
GraphHighlight[g, 
 GraphHighlight -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 
   5 \[DirectedEdge] 1}]
```

Do anything I have missed?

Comment: You either want `CayleyGraph[..,GraphHighlight -> {edges}]` in the original graph, or `HighlightGraph[g,{edges}]`. I.e. (rather confusingly) `GraphHighlight` is an option, while `HighlightGraph` is a function.

Comment: @GeorgeVarnavides Oh god, Thanks very very much. May I ask if you think this is a meaningful post?

Comment: @yode Minor comment: you mention that you want to highlight the path 1→4→5 but in your command you close the path; i.e 1→4→5→1.

Comment: @bmf I have fixed it, thanks

Comment: my reply to your other question: I think that the question makes sense to stay as it is. It's well written and maybe others can benefit. In principle I am an advocate of having answers rather than answers in the comments, so I am hoping that @GeorgeVarnavides will post something

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Posting my comment above as an answer, so it's easier for others to find:

`GraphHighlight` is an option to `Graph`-like functions, while `HighlightGraph` is a function which acts on graphs.

As such, you either want `CayleyGraph[..,GraphHighlight -> {edges}]` in the original graph, or `HighlightGraph[g,{edges}]`. Both give the following result:

```
HighlightGraph[g,{1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[DirectedEdge]1}]
```

[image]